# How to get the reason for onUnloadEvent getting triggered

Tags: html, browser, internet-explorer-8

In Html page when I am closing the browser I am showing message using

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmClose;
                function confirmClose(event){}
```

But the same event is getting triggered for the following conditions also
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms536973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> - Close the current window.
> - Navigate to another location by entering a new address or selecting a Favorite.
> - Click the Back, Forward, Refresh, or Home button.
> - Click an anchor that refers the browser to another document.
> - Invoke the anchor.click method.
> - Invoke the document.write method.
> - Invoke the document.open method.
> - Invoke the document.close method.
> - Invoke the window.close method.
> - Invoke the window.open method, providing the possible value _self for the window name.
> - Invoke the window.navigate or NavigateAndFind method.
> - Invoke the location.replace method.
> - Invoke the location.reload method.
> - Specify a new value for the location.href property.
> - Submit a form to the address specified in the ACTION attribute via the INPUT type=submit control, or invoke the form.submit method.

How can i get what is the reason for triggering the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, generally you can't. The closest you can get is, if the action that triggers the close event also triggers another event, such as clicking on a link, then you can catch that event and set a flag. For example, for clicking on a link (using jQuery):

```
var linkHasBeenClicked = false;

$('a').click(function() {
  linkHasBeenClicked = true;
});

function confirmClose(event){
  if (linkHasBeenClicked) {
     // ...
  } else {
     // ...
  }
  linkHasBeenClicked = false;
}
```